# Error el Mysql al subir al hosting con Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

he cambiado los datos en .env con los nuevos datos que me da el hosting de su base de datos y cuando voy a ingresar me da un error :

Estoy usando el webhostapp.com como hosting
Y he cambiado en opciones la versión del php a 5.5

```
ErrorException in MySqlConnector.php line 57:
Wrong COM_STMT_PREPARE response size. Received 7
in MySqlConnector.php line 57
at HandleExceptions->handleError('2', 'Wrong COM_STMT_PREPARE response size. Received 7', '/storage/ssd1/977/4959977/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/MySqlConnector.php', '57', array('config' => array('driver' => 'mysql', 'host' => 'localhost', 'database' => 'NOMBREBBDD', 'username' => 'NOMBREUSUARIO', 'password' => 'CONTRASEÑA', 'charset' => 'utf8', 'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci', 'prefix' => '', 'strict' => false, 'name' => 'mysql'), 'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=NOMBREBBDD', 'options' => array('0', '2', '0', false, false), 'connection' => object(PDO), 'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci', 'charset' => 'utf8', 'names' => 'set names 'utf8' collate 'utf8_unicode_ci''))
at PDO->prepare('set session sql_mode=''') in MySqlConnector.php line 57
at MySqlConnector->connect(array('driver' => 'mysql', 'host' => 'localhost', 'database' => 'NOMBREBBDD', 'username' => 'NOMBREUSU', 'password' => 'CONTRASEÑA', 'charset' => 'utf8', 'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci', 'prefix' => '', 'strict' => false, 'name' => 'mysql')) in ConnectionFactory.php line 60
at ConnectionFactory->createSingleConnection(array('driver' => 'mysql', 'host' => 'localhost', 'database' => 'NOMBREBBDD', 'username' => 'NOMBREUSU', 'password' => 'CONTRASEÑA', 'charset' => 'utf8', 'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci', 'prefix' => '', 'strict' => false, 'name' => 'mysql')) in ConnectionFactory.php line 49
at ConnectionFactory->make(array('driver' => 'mysql', 'host' => 'localhost', 'database' => 'NOMBREBBDD', 'username' => 'NOMBREUSUARIO', 'password' => 'CONTRASEÑA', 'charset' => 'utf8', 'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci', 'prefix' => '', 'strict' => false, 'name' => 'mysql'), 'mysql') in DatabaseManager.php line 175
at DatabaseManager->makeConnection('mysql') in DatabaseManager.php line 67
at DatabaseManager->connection() in DatabaseManager.php line 296
at DatabaseManager->__call('table', array('usuario')) in Facade.php line 215
at Facade::__callStatic('table', array('usuario')) in Conexion.php line 27
at Conexion->existeUsuario('maria') in administrador.php line 40
at administrador->login(object(Request))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(administrador), 'login'), array(object(Request))) in Controller.php line 256
at Controller->callAction('login', array(object(Request))) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 164
at ControllerDispatcher->call(object(administrador), object(Route), 'login') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 112
at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 114
at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(object(administrador), object(Route), object(Request), 'login') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 68
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request), 'App\Http\Controllers\administrador', 'login') in Route.php line 203
at Route->runWithCustomDispatcher(object(Request)) in Route.php line 134
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 708
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 710
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 674
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 635
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 236
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 50
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 62
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 122
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 87
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es un problema conocido en algunos hosting gratuitos, normalmente se soluciona configurando el atributo `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` en las opciones de la conexión:

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    //.......
    'options'   => [PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true,]
],
```

Comment: Perfecto, eres un crack ;)

Answer (score 0):

En el archivo de config/database.php  agrega este código

```
'mysql' => [
'driver' => 'mysql',
'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
//.......
'options'   => [PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true,]
```

],

espero solucione tu problema.

Comment: ¿qué tiene esto de distinto a mi respuesta? -1